# Running a python script when a new file is created

Tags: python, file

I have a folder that stores a bunch of jpg images. When a new image is added to this folder I need to run a python script on it.

Is this possible? If so, how? One potential solution I saw was [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/) but have not seen any robust examples of it.

Comment: Take a look at [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the [watchdog library](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) is a better thing to use here as creimers mentioned. I have used it as follows to monitor a folder for new files:

```
import time 
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event): # when file is created
        # do something, eg. call your function to process the image
        print "Got event for file %s" % event.src_path 

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() # create event handler
# set observer to use created handler in directory
observer.schedule(event_handler, path='/folder/to/watch')
observer.start()

# sleep until keyboard interrupt, then stop + rejoin the observer
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os                                                                       
import pyinotify                                                                

WATCH_FOLDER = os.path.expanduser('~')                                          

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):                                     
    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):                                    
        """"                                                                    
        Writtable file was closed.                                              
        """                                                                     
        if event.pathname.endswith('.jpg'):                                     
            print event.pathname                                                

    def process_IN_MOVED_TO(self, event):                                       
        """                                                                     
        File/dir was moved to Y in a watched dir (see IN_MOVE_FROM).            
        """                                                                     
        if event.pathname.endswith('.jpg'):                                     
            print event.pathname                                                

    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):                                         
        """                                                                     
        File/dir was created in watched directory.                              
        """                                                                     
        if event.pathname.endswith('.jpg'):                                     
            print event.pathname                                                


def main():                                                                     
    # watch manager                                                             
    mask = pyinotify.IN_CREATE | pyinotify.IN_MOVED_TO | pyinotify.IN_CLOSE_WRITE
    watcher = pyinotify.WatchManager()                                          
    watcher.add_watch(WATCH_FOLDER,                                             
                      mask,                                                     
                      rec=True)                                                 
    handler = EventHandler()                                                    
    # notifier                                                                  
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(watcher, handler)                             
    notifier.loop()                                                             

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import threading
import glob
import os


f1 = glob.glob('*.txt')
def Status():


  threading.Timer(1.0, Status).start()
  f2 = glob.glob('*.txt')
  f3 =  set(f2) - set(f1)
  if len(f3) == 0:
    print " No new file"
  else:
    print "new file arrived do something"
    print list(f3)[0]

Status()
```

Run this script and copy text files one by one in the same directory where this python script is running. It will tell you the name of the recently copied file. You can add more complex condition checking its just a simple example code and can perform the desired operation on newly arrived text file.

The output will be something like this:

```
 No new file
 No new file
 No new file
 No new file
 No new file
new file arrived do something
File_request.txt
new file arrived do something
File_request.txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (another copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (another copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (3rd copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (3rd copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (4th copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (4th copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (4th copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (5th copy).txt
new file arrived do something
File_request (5th copy).txt
```

**Warning:** This code is to demonstrate the basic concept relevant to the query, I didn't check the robustness of this code.