# Matching cells in CSV to return calculation

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to create a program that will take the most recent 30 CSV files of data within a folder and calculate totals of certain columns. There are 4 columns of data, with the first column being the identifier and the rest being the data related to the identifier. Here's an example:

file1

```
Asset     X      Y      Z
12345    250    100    150
23456    225    150    200
34567    300    175    225
```

file2

```
Asset     X      Y      Z
12345    270    130    100
23456    235    190    270
34567    390    115    265
```

I want to be able to match the asset# in both CSVs to return each columns value and then perform calculations on each column. Once I have completed those calculations I intend on graphing various data as well. So far the only thing I have been able to complete is extracting ALL the data from the CSV file using the following code:

```
csvfile = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\tdjones\\Desktop\\Python Work Files\\FDR*.csv')
listData = []
for files in csvfile:
df = pd.read_csv(files, index_col=0)
listData.append(df)

concatenated_data = pd.concat(listData, sort=False)
group = concatenated_data.groupby('ASSET')['Slip Expense  ($)', 'Net Win  ($)'].sum()

group.to_csv("C:\\Users\\tdjones\\Desktop\\Python Work Files\\Test\\NewFDRConcat.csv", header=('Slip Expense', 'Net WIn'))
```

I am very new to Python so any and all direction is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: You are just one instruction from `concat`enating all data in one `DataFrame`. As for querying data - I suggest you consult with [SQL GROUP BY Comparison](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/comparison_with_sql.html#group-by)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably also set the asset number as the index while you're reading the data, since this can help with sifting through data. So

```
rd = pd.read_csv(files, index_col=0)
```

Then you can do as Alex Yu suggested and just pick all the data from a specific asset number out when you're done using

```
asset_data = rd.loc[asset_number, column_name]
```

You'll generally need to format the data in the DataFrame before you append it to the list if you only want specific inputs. Exactly how to do that naturally depends specifically on what you want i.e. what kind of calculations you perform.

If you want a function that just returns all the data for one specific asset, you could do something along the lines of

```
def get_asset(asset_number):

    csvfile = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\tdjones\\Desktop\\Python Work Files\\*.csv')

    asset_data = []

    for file in csvfile:

        data = [line for line in open(file, 'r').read().splitlines()
            if line.split(',')[0] == str(asset_num)]

        for line in data:
            asset_data.append(line.split(','))

    return pd.DataFrame(asset_data, columns=['Asset', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'], dtype=float)
```

Although how well the above performs is going to depend on how large the dataset is your going through. Something like the above method needs to search through every line and perform several high level functions on each line, so it could potentially be problematic if you have millions of lines of data in each file.

Also, the above assumes that all data elements are strings of numbers (so can be cast to integers or floats). If thats not the case, leave the dtype argument out of the DataFrame definition, but keep in mind that everything returned is stored as a string then.

Comment: each file contains less than 2600 rows of data (78,000 rows across 30 files) and 20 columns of data(I'm only using 5 columns of info for my report). Everything in the file is a digit but when I pull it in through python it returns str and int unless I reformat all cells to 'General'(most of the numbers are related to Money). My goal, however, is to simply drop the file into a folder and it perform the work without any further adjustment needed.

Comment: If you want to monitor the directory for specific changes (i.e. file additions), you could look into the inotify and watchdog modules (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479511/running-a-python-script-when-a-new-file-is-created). Ive never actually used them myself, but I know of a few similar projects that they helped with.

Comment: You can give a DataFrame the `dtype` argument when you define it, which will cast all the string values (if they really are all numbers) to the specified type. So, for example `df = pd.DataFrame(data, dtype=int)` will try to cast all values to integer types. Note however that this will only work if all values can be successfully cast

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you need to add for your code  [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) of your `listData`

So it will became:

```
csvfile = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\tdjones\\Desktop\\Python Work Files\\*.csv')
listData = []
for files in csvfile:
    rd = pd.read_csv(files)
    listData.append(rd)
concatenated_data = pd.concat(listData)
```

After that you can use aggregate functions with this `concatenated_data` `DataFrame` such as: `concatenated_data['A'].max()`, `concatenated_data['A'].count()`, 'groupby`s etc.

Comment: So I see how this combined the information into one file but I'm not sure how to perform calculations on the date of columns with matching Asset #s. Essentially the only calculations will be addition and subtraction if that helps.

Comment: Correction: not **"into one file"** but **"one DataFrame"**. Clarification: "calculations on the **date** of columns" - "date" or "data"? In case it's data than it's must be `concatenated_data.groupby('Asset')['X'].sum()` and such. If it's some "date"s  - please clarify

Comment: calculations on the DATA of columns. Sorry. I did the groupby.sum() but It's not actually summing the data requested. Am I doing something wrong? here's the  code: csvfile = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\tdjones\\Desktop\\Python Work Files\\*.csv')
listData = []
for files in csvfile:
    rd = pd.read_csv(files, index_col=0)
    listData.append(rd)
concatenated_data = pd.concat(listData, sort=False)
group = concatenated_data.groupby('ASSET')['Slip Expense  ($)'].sum()

group.to_csv("C:\\Users\\tdjones\\Desktop\\Python Work Files\\Test\\NewFDRConcat.csv", header=False)

Comment: Please edit your question add **Edit section** and copy your current code below. Personaly I like `assets_data` more than my long `concatenated_data`. Before you continue - look what `concatenated_data.columns`/`assets_data.columns` will return

Comment: I have edited the question to include my current code. I tried printing concatenated_data.columns...all it did was print the Column names. Is there something else it should have done?