# Checking a folder if no new files were added into it and generate an alert if no new files were added

Tags: python-3.x, windows, directory, python-watchdog

I'm trying to create a program with Python that checks if a folder has a new file(s) or not.

I had an instance where there was a technical error and no new files were being added to a folder. I didn't know until a couple days later.

I want to generate an alert (a text file or email alert or something) if no new files were added to the folder.

I have a test folder with two files:

```
Name       Date Modified
doc1.txt   6/23/22 
doc2.txt   6/23/22
```

If I run a program now it should say `"No files added since 6/23/22"` as an alert then end program.
But, if I add a new file today:

```
Name       Date Modified
doc1.txt   6/23/22 
doc2.txt   6/23/22
doc3.txt   7/25/22
```

The program should output nothing and end or say "there is an event with doc3.txt".

So far I have something like this I found here: [Running a python script when a new file is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23479511/running-a-python-script-when-a-new-file-is-created) as I see Watchdog is good for this. It's sort of similar to what I want, just need to remove the while loop as I have my own scheduling software to run the program everyday to check. But is there a better way than this?

```
import os, time, datetime
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

path_to_watch = 'Testing Folder'

class ExampleHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event): # when file is created
        # do something, eg. call your function to process the image
        print("Got event for file %s" % event.src_path) 

observer = Observer()
event_handler = ExampleHandler() # create event handler
# set observer to use created handler in directory
observer.schedule(event_handler, path=path_to_watch)
observer.start()


# sleep until keyboard interrupt, then stop + rejoin the observer
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        exit()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    observer.stop()

observer.join()
```

Comment: If you just want to run the script once a day to check if there's a new file, maybe create a log file? When the script runs it logs the date/time of the check. The next time it runs it reads the log file for the last date/time check, and looks to see if any files have been created since that date/time.

Comment: It seems like you only need to check this daily. Why not just create a script that reads the directory, sorts by creation date, and maybe records that file in a txt file. Then, assuming this is a windows machine, create a task schedule that runs once a day.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to use datetime, glob and notification to do this.